# Obtener el innerText y usarlo como parámetro en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo una agenda en donde al agregar un contacto, se guarda en el LocalStorage y se genera un div como el siguiente:

```
<div class="contacto">
    <h1 class="name">Juan </h1>
    <h2>Correo: @gmail.com</h2>
    <h2>Teléfono:12345</h2>
</div>
```

Para eliminar cualquiera, necesito el nombre del contacto para de ahí, obtener su index y poder eliminarlo del localStorage; y quería que esto sucediera al darle click al div del contacto que se eliminará.

Entonces cuando quiero borrar un contacto, le agrego a todos los divs un eventListener:

```
function seleccionarContacto(){
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("contacto");
var y = document.getElementsByClassName("name");

for (var  i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    var text = y[i].innerText;
    x[i].addEventListener("click", function(){ eliminarContacto(text); });
 }
}
```

Donde le asigno a cada div la misma función pero con un parámetro diferente, y con el parámetro "text" obtendría el texto de la etiqueta h1 del div; sin embargo siempre me devuelve el último nombre, por ejemplo, si tengo 3 divs, me devuelve el nombre del último div sin importar en cual le de click. Me está tomando i como su último valor en todos mis divs.

¿Alguien sabe como resolver esto? ¿O se les ocurre alguna mejor manera de hacerlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

El problema está en que al realizar el bucle `for`, si bien le estás añadiendo una función al evento `click`, el valor de la variable que recibe luego la función `eliminarContacto()` que ejecutas al hacer clic sobre el `div` será el último valor que tiene `text` al salir del bucle.

Veamos:

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("contacto");
var y = document.getElementsByClassName("name");

for (var  i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
  var text = y[i].innerText;
  // text es una variable que va cambiando su valor a medida que se ejecuta el bucle
  console.log(text);
  x[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log(text); //<= cuando se hace clic, muestra el último valor que tenga la variable text
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="contacto">
  <h2 class="name">Juan</h2>
  <h4>Correo: juan@email.com</h4>
  <h4>Teléfono:12345</h4>
</div>
<div class="contacto">
  <h2 class="name">Pedro</h2>
  <h4>Correo: pedro@email.com</h4>
  <h4>Teléfono:54321</h4>
</div>
<div class="contacto">
  <h2 class="name">Pablo</h2>
  <h4>Correo: pablo@email.com</h4>
  <h4>Teléfono:55555</h4>
</div>
```

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución es sencilla, debes trabajar con `this`, que hará referencia al elemento `div` dentro de la función que pasas como `callback` al evento clic. Y es allí donde vas a capturar el nombre del contacto, no antes.

Tu código podría verse de la siguiente forma:

```js
var contactos = document.getElementsByClassName('contacto');

for(var i = 0; i < contactos.length; i++) {
  // añadimos una función al evento click
  contactos[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault;
    // capturamos el nombre usando this, que hará referencia únicamente
    // al div sobre el que se hizo clic
    var nombre = this.getElementsByClassName('name')[0].innerText; // posición 0 => primer elemento (en teoría el único)
    console.log(nombre);
    // aqui ya puedes pasar el nombre a tu función eliminarContacto
    //eliminarContacto(nombre);
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="contacto">
  <h2 class="name">Juan</h2>
  <h4>Correo: juan@email.com</h4>
  <h4>Teléfono:12345</h4>
</div>
<div class="contacto">
  <h2 class="name">Pedro</h2>
  <h4>Correo: pedro@email.com</h4>
  <h4>Teléfono:54321</h4>
</div>
<div class="contacto">
  <h2 class="name">Pablo</h2>
  <h4>Correo: pablo@email.com</h4>
  <h4>Teléfono:55555</h4>
</div>
```

Una sugerencia de buena práctica es que uses nombres más coherentes en tus variables, usar sólo letras es confuso:

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("contacto");
var y = document.getElementsByClassName("name");
```

Se entiende mejor si hacemos:

```js
var contactos = document.getElementsByClassName("contacto"); // puede ser 0 o varios, por eso en plural.
var nombre = this.getElementsByClassName("name")[0].innerText; // aqui es singular, porque es 1 sólo nombre.
```

Espero que esto aclare tus dudas.

Comment: Muchísimas Gracias si que funciono! tomare en cuenta tu sugerencia tambien; pero me surge una duda ¿Por qué usar el `event.preventDefault()`? ¿Cuál es el evento que está deteniendo?

Comment: Eso es algo casi automático que coloco siempre que trabajo con formularios y botones. Normalmente un botón de un formulario ejecuta el evento `submit` del mismo por defecto. Puedes quitarlo, ya que no hace falta, al no estar trabajando con un formulario. Es una costumbre para mi siempre colocarlo, pero no es necesario. Saludos

Comment: Me alegra haber podido ayudar. Si te ha sido útil la respuesta la puedes [aceptar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) como válida. Puedes leer [*¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) ;). Saludos